# Does an original service disconnect without neutral bonding violate code?

Tags: electrical, grounding, bonding

Single family home built in 1987.  Question is regarding the as-built: Is it grandfathered and does not be updated?

There is no neutral-ground bond in the 100A breaker equipped main service disconnect located outside next to the meter box. Only the ground cable to the service panel and a cable to a ground rod are present on a box bonded terminal bar in this box.  The neutral just goes thru the service disconnect box, not terminated to anything, going on into the separate meter box.

There is a neutral-ground bond in the garage main lug 20 space service panel, consisting of a #6 copper wire between separate neutral and ground bars.

There is a 2-2-2-4 service entrance cable run from the disconnect box to a service panel in the garage, not in conduit.

Since there is only 1 neutral-ground bonding point the intent of NEC code that no neutral current can flow in the grounding system under normal conditions is satisfied. It just is not bonded where the 2008 and later NEC book says.

My question is since this pre-dates 2008 NEC and there is no new electrical work happening is this grandfathered?   Any safety concern?

---

Addressing the questions in comments:

- The meter, outdoor box w 100 main breaker, and the 20 space main lug breaker box are all on or in the same building, a single family residence.
- The metal outdoor box is unlocked and has a 100 Amp 2-pole breaker.  That is the means of service disconnect as well as the protective device for the entrance cable. It is located outside adjacent to the outdoor service meter box.
- The inside box is a main lug 20 space 2-pole load center with separate ground bar and neutral bar. It is located in the residence's garage.
- The connecting cable is a 2-2-2-4 copper conductor entrance cable, not in conduit. Approximately a 50' wire run inside walls and across attic.
- The outside box has an AC Disconnect label on its door.

Comment: It's outside my expertise, but I think if the one and only bond is in the one and only panelboard then it's both grandfathered and not even a concern as is.

Comment: Ask the Local Authority Having Jurisdiction ... But, yeah, if you didn't create the situation it's probably grandfathered, and it's safe.

Comment: Is there another main breaker past this disconnect? Or is the next place a main-lug panel with more than 6 breakers?

Comment: Terminology is losing me, so I'll only offer some pints for consideration. Before 1993(?) feeders to a detached building were treated as service feeders and bonding was required. Bonding was still required at service disconnect. Also if metal conduit  is connecting the meter cabinet and service disconnect the a bonding jumper is functionally redundant because the neutral lugs in the meter cabinet are mounted directly to and bonded to the cabinet. I don't have Code book that old, but I don't think that that bonding exempted the disconnect bonding requirement back then.

Comment: Is the outside box actually labeled as "Main Service Disconnect"? Is the main breaker (if any, please [edit] to answer that question and these ones) labeled that way? That point can matter, IIRC. The outside switch serves the emergency shutdown function but the inside main (if present) could be designated as the "Main Service Disconnect" by labeling it that way. *I think...*

Comment: Pictures of the various components, without covers if safe/possible (don't try to remove the cover from the meter!), and labeled as to where they are in the electrical flow, would probably be of additional help.